# How to get a list of IPs from Ansible yml inventory for use in a shell script?

Tags: bash, ansible, jq, fish

How to get a list of all the IPs in an Ansible inventory for a pattern, for use in a script outside of Ansible?

Answer (score 3):

The query can be simplified

```bash
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory.yml --list | jq -r '._meta[][].ansible_host'
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
1.1.1.1
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Nice, thank you for that simplified version!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the `ansible-inventory` command and then use the `json` `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK` but first `ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS` [needs to be enabled](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16194#issuecomment-311340681) and pipe the output to `jq` for processing just the IPS. Here is a the command, adjust the `--limit` pattern (or remove for all) and the `--inventory` path:

Fish: Create test file

```
echo "all:
  children:
    resolvers:
      hosts:
        host1:
          ansible_host: 8.8.8.8
        host2:
          ansible_host: 8.8.4.4
        host3:
          ansible_host: 1.1.1.1
  hosts:
    otherhost:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.1" > /tmp/inventory.yml
```

Bash: Create test file

```bash
cat > /tmp/inventory.yml <<EOF
all:
  children:
    resolvers:
      hosts:
        host1:
          ansible_host: 8.8.8.8
        host2:
          ansible_host: 8.8.4.4
        host3:
          ansible_host: 1.1.1.1
  hosts:
    otherhost:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.1
EOF
```

Then, output just the IPS:

```bash
ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS=yes \
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json \
ansible-inventory \
    --inventory /tmp/inventory.yml \
    --list \
        | jq --raw-output '
            ._meta[] 
            | to_entries[] 
            | .value.ansible_host
          '
```

Output:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
1.1.1.1
192.168.1.1
```

Or output specific IPS with `--limit` filter, use * for wildcard:

```bash
ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS=yes \
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json \
ansible-inventory \
    --inventory /tmp/inventory.yml \
    --limit "resolv*" \
    --list \
        | jq --raw-output '
            ._meta[] 
            | to_entries[] 
            | .value.ansible_host
          '
```

Output:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
1.1.1.1
```

Comment: This implies you've set `ansible_host` for every single host in your inventory which is far from being the general case. Most inventories use fqdns as inventory hostnames and you then rely on DNS resolution.

Comment: That makes sense for some situations, maybe even most. However, there are plenty of projects that have inventory with no public DNS, and also some that are in private IP space as well.